# CakePHP vs codeigniter - I'm experienced in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, codeigniter, frameworks, performance

First of all I don't mind the "writing more code" attitude that CI has so I don't really care about that. Right now I'm pretty good in CakePHP (I have like 3-4 years in it) and I think it has certain flaws the biggest one being its speed and I was thinking of passing over to CI but I need to know something..

My simplest application in CakePHP (with admin and some data in table - multilanguage) takes about 0.2 Seconds of code processing. I was wondering if anyone has a time for Code Igniter for a certain website. I'm curious if it's worth the learning time.

I installed code igniter and at first it seemed imensly fast but I'm just worried that if I keep adding components, models, helpers and everything to it it will slow down (maybe more than cake). So.. I'm actually looking for an example of CI website and the exact time it loads... (down to at least 2 decimals).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/164928/#791087) will give you a fairly good answer, as the site in question is not a "Hello World" but a fully fledged Site with database access helpers and libraries loaded, etc...

[image]

I'm sure some will have arguments about its validity (probably CakePHP proponents), but it's not every day you have a site re-developed between frameworks and compared.

**UPDATE**

Again, for those that don't want to follow the link to the thread, the tester actually upgraded the site to CI 2.0, using modular extentions, caching, other optimizations and re-tested
[image: test after upgrading same site to 2.0 with extra optimizations]

Comment: hah, downvote w/o comment (probably a cakePHP fan)

Comment: Wow, Codeigniter 2.0 is surprisingly a lot faster than the 1.7.x releases. I wonder what spurred the dramatic increase when not much really changed jumping from 1.7 to 2.0?